# "non-static variable cannot ..." error - MarshMallow permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am trying to implement the permissionChecker for Marshmallow 6.0

In my `onCreate` I put the permission check method (this is where the error happens every time on `onCreate()`, see error below).

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Permission(); 
    //other codes here
}
```

And this is INSIDE the MainActivity class and is called on `onCreate()`

```
    //Permision code that will be checked in the method onRequestPermissionsResult
    public int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;

    //We are calling this method to check the permission status
    public boolean isReadStorageAllowed() {
        //Getting the permission status
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        //If permission is granted returning true
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return true;

        //If permission is not granted returning false
        return false;
    }

    //Requesting permission
    public void requestStoragePermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }

        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Permission(){
        ////Android marshmallow new Permission Code////
        if (isReadStorageAllowed()) {
            //If permission is already having then showing the toast
            return;
        }
        //If permission is already having then showing the toast
        else{
            requestStoragePermission();

        }
    }

}
```

**This happens only if the permission is off, if I enable it manually from settings it works just fine.**

> " Error on main activity "
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>                                                        at com.nephi.motionmusicplayer_2mp.MusicService.updateSongList(MusicService.java:210)
>                                                        at com.nephi.motionmusicplayer_2mp.MusicService.init(MusicService.java:323)
>                                                        at com.nephi.motionmusicplayer_2mp.MusicService.onCreate(MusicService.java:110)

Comment: you mean to say, you have `Activity` class within `Service` class??

Comment: sorry i just moved it outside the MusicService class, i realized i can't reference "this" from service because it's not an activity class in the first place.. but the problem still persists if i want to call Permission(); inside it. the main activity calls MusicService , i already implemented Permission() in mainActivity and it worked

Comment: This line `PermissionChecker.Permission()` from which `Activity`/`Fragment` are you calling it??

Comment: @JimitPatel i just deleted the whole class from MusicSevice.. so now, when i run the app , Main Activity crashes because of " ADDED IN POST ABOVE , CHECK IT " and that happens only because the storage permission is disabled , if i enable it manually it works flawlessly. Do you see what is my problem ?

Comment: Check something like this - start the service if your have permissions, else don't start.

Comment: @JimitPatel FIXED ! I made something close to what you said and it works great !

Comment: I know you will be able to fix it, as I was not able to understand what you were trying to say and wrote, but I know what all could have gone wrong. So was just directing you, to help yourself. ;) Enjoy!!